# Ratio between nonnegative summands

Tags: inequality, summation

I am trying to understand why this inequality is true:
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} y_i} \le \max_i\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\}$$.
where $x_i,y_i \ge0$

Comment: So, what exactly do you understand about each of these things already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite it as:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i \le \max_i\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} y_i$$

Then, let $M=\max_i\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\}$, and we have $My_i \le \max_i\{x_i\}$, so that:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_i \le \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}\max_i x_i$$

which is true.